# Sidekiq Unique Job Processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redis, capistrano, resque, sidekiq

I need to assure that no more than one job per user_id is worked simultaneosly by any of the 25 workers to avoid deadlocks.

I have tried sidekiq unique jobs but deadlocks keep occoring because it keeps trying to process all pending jobs on the queue without looking for the user_id on the params.

Thank you

```rb
class MyWork   
  include Sidekiq::Worker   
  sidekiq_options :queue => "critical", unique: true,
                   unique_args: ->(args) { [ args.user_id ] }


  def perform(work_params)
```

Comment: Here is a not so great idea: You could probably maintain a table that contains the user ids that are being processed. Every time you have to start processing, take a look at the table and the current user id; start the processing only if the user id is not in the table. If it is in the table, push the job back to the queue.

Comment: eventually that may be a not so bad idea :)

Comment: You should try to use the in memory store provided by redis to do this, instead of activerecord.

Comment: I will investigate and possibly try that redis memory store if iy saves on resorces and provides data quicker, never heard about it @Vineeth.

Answer (score 4):

The sidekiq_option `args` is an array that has your `works_params` on the first position. You should then do:

```
class MyWork
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :queue => "critical", unique: until_executed, 
                   unique_args: ->(args) { [ args.first.user_id ] }

  def perform(work_params)
```

Note that `unique: true` is deprecated, so you should use `unique: until_executed` or whatever fits best for your worker. See [here](https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs#locking) for other options.